# VBA Compiler Won't Allow Use of Parentheses Around Method Arguments

Tags: excel, vba

I'm curious why Excel's VBA editor will accept this line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels rowlevels:=1, columnlevels:=1
```

But I get a "Compile Error:  Expected:=" message box when I type this line of code:

```
ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1)
```

Excel's help says that the ShowLevels method's syntax is expression.ShowLevels(RowLevels, ColumnLevels) and the editor lists this as the correct syntax when I right click and choose Parameter Info.

Does anyone know why this occurs?  I'd prefer to use the parentheses just because it looks cleaner and takes up less space.

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: If you want the `()` then use the keyword `Call` as in `Call ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1)`

Comment: Wow, it's really that simple??  I thought Call was only used when referencing another sub.  Why would I need it for a built-in VBA method?

Comment: Oops you may be right.  I did not read that it was a built in method.  Try it and let me know if it worked.  If not sorry to waste your time.

Comment: Oh, sorry that I didn't mention that you were right.  I tested it and it definitely works, I'm just perplexed why I would need to do that.  Back to googling, I guess.

Comment: Look at that, even a broken watch is right twice a day.

Comment: BTW, you can call it like this: `ActiveSheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1,1`

Comment: You're right:).  I wonder if it's the same principle as to why there is a difference between Msgbox "text" and Msgbox("text").  I think I remember someone explaining to me that when you use parentheses it's like calling a procedure, which would explain why placing Call before the line when using parentheses works and how you don't need Call when not using parentheses.  Something for me to mull over and try to remember.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: You also use parenthesis when returning a value, as this function returns a variant, you can still say a=Activesheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1), but not Activesheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1,1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also use parenthesis when returning a value, as this function returns a variant, you can still say a=Activesheet.Outline.ShowLevels(1,1), but not Activesheet.Outline.ShowLevels 1,1

Comment: Ah, I see.  That must have been why I was getting the compiler error.  I was using parentheses but I wasn't setting the line equal to a variable.  It's slowly starting to make sense.  I'm happy that the editor is not broken like I thought 15 minutes ago.  Thank you!